# How can a US citizen living abroad In Honduras return to the USA?

Tags: usa, international-travel, us-citizens, honduras

Thanks for taking time answering this. I'm quite confused with what my options are.

I was born in the United States (new Orleans, Louisiana) in 1994. As soon as I was allowed to travel on a plane, my family decided to go back to live in Honduras. Since then I've been living in Honduras. I'm now 23 years old and I have no idea on what I should do to go back to the USA (is it really as simple as just take a plane and fly there?) Things here in Honduras have gotten ugly and unstable. I don't have any family over there so I don't have a place to stay and I don't know if there are any programs that can help me start living there.

**Other details about me:**

- My passport is up to date.
- I also have my original security number with me.
- I've finished college in Honduras.
- I also have Honduran nationality.
- I'm not married and I don't have kids.

I want to move and start a life in the USA. For multiple reasons including better quality of life, security, finding a life partner (I'm gay and that here is kind of a problem).

My plan was to save some money and buy a plane ticket, move to a state and try to find a job and live with the saved-up money. The problem is this will take a lot of time as the national currency over here has 23 times less value compared to the dollar (1$ = 23.5 lempiras).

So is this my only option or I have other ways to go back to the USA?

Comment: This is more of a personal finance question than a travel one. Check out https://money.stackexchange.com

Comment: "My passport is up to date"  **Do you mean your >> USA << passport?**

Comment: Yes, as long as your passport is a **USA** passport, you have complete rights.  You only need a one-way ticket, you do not need to explain yourself in any way, you won't be hassled at all.

Comment: Many of the issues here are better suited to [Expatriates.SE] than to [Travel.SE] or [Money.SE].  Also, note that the 23-fold difference inthe currency doesn't necessarily mean that things cost 23 times more.  Somethingthat costs 94 lempiras might cost $4, in which case the cost would be about the same, or it might cost $2 or $8.  Comparing cost of living can be complicated.

Comment: @Fattie Yeah I meant USA passport. Oh its nice to know is that simple.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the links I didn't know of those stack exchange categories. Will look into them ty

Comment: You might be able to get help from a social organization for gay people, even if they can only help you find other sources of help. It is worth it to search websites and maybe send a few e-mails or other messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So is this my only option or I have other ways to go back to USA?

I'm unsure whether this is more suitable for Expats, so I am going to only address the "travel" part.

Yes, if your passport is up to date, it is really as simple as getting on a plane and fly here. I run a quick search and there are some cheap tickets - a flight from SAP to FLL on Nov 22nd on Spirit is USD 94, which is quite reasonable.

As far as I know, there are no government-sponsored "programs" which would pay for your plane ticket or moving. However you might find a private sponsor to cover your travel costs. For example if you get a job in the USA, the company might pay your relocation expenses. Some companies would also want a prospective candidate to come for a job interview, and would cover your travel costs as well.

Finally, don't be afraid. Plenty of immigrants come to the USA every year from poorer countries, with few resources, limited English and insecure immigration status such as work visas. And most make it through.